# How do you use GPU and TPU in kaggle?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network, data-science, kaggle

I have enabled the GPU option in accelerator tab but when I try to train my model GPU is not processing my data instead only CPU is processing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically use the packages like https://rapids.ai/ to move data from CPU to GPU. I am assuming you using something like `pandas` to do data operations.

Comment: Can you please tell me the procedure to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem in your training code where you might not be properly sending model and input to device and thus ending up only using your CPU. Check out these Kaggle examples on how to use:

- TPUs: https://www.kaggle.com/docs/tpu#tpu9
- GPUs: https://www.kaggle.com/rj1993/kernel-with-gpu-example

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but even if I try these steps the data is processing on CPU only. Can you please explain the process in brief.